# Issue with activities?

Tags: java, android, variables, android-activity, counter

I have been trying to fix this for a long time. Basically, I have made an app that calls another activity (from an array) at random, and displays it. I wanted to try and count the number of activities I have in my app.

**So, I created a new java class, to use the variable in it globally:**
[image]

As you can see, it has the variable activityCountNumber in it. Now, I have the following code in **every** activity:

```
        activityCount.activityCountNumber += 1;
```

This, logically, should take the variable shown above, and increase its value by 1. The weird issue I am having is that when I finally print out the number of activities that I got past, I get some weird number:

[image]

Basically, if I pass 5 activities in 8 seconds, the text on my phone will change to something like:

```
Got passed this many activities: 15 in this many seconds: 8
```

Even though it should be:

```
Got passed this many activities: 5 in this many seconds: 8
```

Code I am using to change activities:
[image]

Please help me, as I have been stuck on this for a very long time. It's odd and interesting at the same time though, because logically, the number being displayed is just random! Thanks for all your help, and if you need to see any other code, just let me know!

Happy Halloween!

```
{Rich}
```

Comment: This sounds like a threading issue... You're changing the same variable from different places and you have no control in what order it's being changed, because more activities are changing the value.
Could you show the code you're using to switch between the different activities?

Comment: did you `finish()` every Activity you were in? you might have counted them twice. one when you got in the `Activity` and one when you came back to the original `Activity`. if you finished them, you will created each again and again so the `onCreate()` will be called

Comment: @amirag How do I finish() an activity? Either way, I want to count the number of activities, regardless of repetition. For example, if the activities run in the following order:  **Activity a, Activity b, Activity c, Activity a, Activity d, Activity b** I would still want a count of 6, regardless that b and a went twice. Do you mind posting an answer with an example? That would be really helpful, and I will make sure to mark it as best answer and like your post if it works! Thanks so much.

Comment: @Darwind Sure thing Darwind! I will update my question with the code that I am using to change the activities. Thanks for your time!

Comment: @Darwind I have updated my question

Comment: @Rich if you would have finished your `Activity` you would have known. basiclly is when the `onDestroy()` is called. i just thought of another idea, maybe you turned your sceend few times? this causes the `Activity` to re-create itself

Comment: @amirag No, I didn't turn my screen. What were you saying about the onDestroy method? I don't have an ondestroy method, do you mind explaining? Thanks

Comment: @Rich it's probably not that. i've read everything again and i saw that you want to count everyactivityt and the order does not matter. i thought the you go to Activity a, then return and then to Activity b. i will rething this question

Comment: @amirag thanks, I appreciate it. Feel free to post an answer too! Thanks for your time :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93890/discussion-between-amirag-and-rich).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.
To find the problem we used the LogCat, every `Activity` we printed the `activityCountNumber` to the Log (a genius idea by Rich) and discovered where was the problem was.

After that we check what causes it and fixed it.

in the end, we took care of the screen rotation so the `Activity` win't call the onCreate again and the problem was solved completely.

happy halloween :)

Comment: **Hey, Amirag. In chat, I remember you asked me to send you a link of my application once it gets released. I just released a big update on it today. It would be really awesome if you downloaded it and wrote a review. Also, if you have anything you want me to add, just email me on the developer email(it says it at the very bottom of the link). So, here it is:** https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.culybrace.ruchir.buttonsmasher **Can't wait to hear your feedback in the form of a review/email. See you later dude!**

Comment: great :) i'll download it right away. looks awsome :D

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to count number of times each activity is fired in your app and once app closes you don't want to retain that number. So when app is running it should give you a count of activities it visited.

If this is the case, then I would want to try this way:-

1) I'll declare long counter in each activities, however I will define it once in first activity only. Then I would pass this counter using putExtra in an intent to every next intent I'm firing. And using getIntent to retrieve this value in every next intent you are sending this value to.

**Alternatively, you may try this way:-**

Define following in your main class, suppose MyData is my main class then-

public class MyData {

private static int data;
  public static int getData() {return data;}

}

then from launched activity, use

int data = MyData.getData() + 1;

Comment: I really appreciate your feedback! Because it is randomly switching, it would be very difficult to do that. I may need to retrieve it at random. Is there any way I can do it with a global variable, so that whenever I need to retrieve it, I can just get the value of the variable? Also, do you know where the weird number that I am getting instead of the correct one is coming from? I am still confused about that. Thanks so much!

Comment: No problem Rich, try with alternative solution I just added.

Comment: Thanks! How will I receive int data though to add one in every activity, since that variable is not global? Basically, we are just making the variable private, and retrieving it from a getter method instead right? Thanks.

Comment: Instead of **int data = MyData.getData() + 1;**

Comment: I did:         **activityCount.getCountNumber()++;**

Comment: But the problem is, I get an error saying: **Variable expected**

Comment: Do you know how to work around this? Thanks so much, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Would this work:      **long x = activityCount.getCountNumber()+1;
        
        activityCount.activityCountNumber = x;**

Comment: Nope, you will have to define a method in each new activities to save new count using sharedpreferance. So once you visit new activity, it should add your activity count and save this new count to sharedpref.

Comment: How do I do that with sharedpref in this case? Sorry, I am really new to sharedPreferences. Also, do you mind explaining why my previous code wasn't working?

Comment: And does the getData method go in my activityCount class?